# Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg.so on Android I am getting Working Directory: null Environment: null error.

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.example.foo/files/ffmpeg -f image2 -i "
+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/img/b%d.jpg " 
+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/a444.mp4");   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ERROR LOG

```
04-09 01:50:45.683: I/Adreno-EGL(18393): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
04-09 01:50:45.713: D/OpenGLRenderer(18393): Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 01:53:56.487: D/dalvikvm(18551): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.sodeneme-1/libffmpeg.so 0x423d7d00
04-09 01:53:56.487: D/dalvikvm(18551): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.sodeneme-1/libffmpeg.so 0x423d7d00
04-09 01:53:56.487: D/dalvikvm(18551): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.sodeneme-1/libffmpeg.so 0x423d7d00, skipping init
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.example.sodeneme/files/ffmpeg, -f, image2, -i, /storage/emulated/0/img/b%d.jpg, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/a444.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at com.example.sodeneme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-09 01:53:56.537: W/System.err(18551):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 01:53:56.547: W/System.err(18551): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
04-09 01:53:56.547: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
04-09 01:53:56.547: W/System.err(18551):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
04-09 01:53:56.547: W/System.err(18551):    ... 18 more
04-09 01:53:56.577: I/Adreno-EGL(18551): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
04-09 01:53:56.607: D/OpenGLRenderer(18551): Enabling debug mode 0
```

PERMISSIONS

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to add this permission to your **AndroidManifest.xml file**:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: I added permission list on top

Comment: I see you just add info about your AndroidManifest.xml. Can you debug and see what `Process` returned? Then, check if the file exists at "/data/data/com.example.foo/files/" before continuing.

Comment: I can't see in data from DDMS probably because Its not rooted.

Comment: Ah yes, `/data/data/` directory is only available to system apps or devices that are rooted. So, instead of writing to this directory, perhaps you can write to your app's own private directories or to the internal, or external SD card.

Comment: I solved it by using getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir

Comment: Hey @Mert, could you tell me how? i cant get this to work. where is the ffmpeg located inside of the nativeLibraryDir? its still file not found for me :(

Comment: @datayeah did you fixed that issue?

Comment: @Shahar, yes. as far as i remember, i ended up not using a .so file but an actual ffmpeg precompiled binary inside the "raw" resources folder and copied it from the raw resources to the internal storage of my app (during app startup). then i chmod'ed the binary to 777 and i was able to start the process from within the app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the `/data/data/com.example.foo/files/ffmpeg` file has the correct file permissions.

You can check file permission with the following command :

```
String[] command = new String[]{"/system/bin/ls", "-l",
                                "/data/data/com.example.foo/files/ffmpeg" };
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
int read;

String output = "";

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.concat(line + "\n");
    Log.w("myApp", "[[output]]:" + line);
}  
reader.close();
process.waitFor();
```

The output would be something like this (depending on actual permissions , in this case the permissions are 777) :

```
[[output]]:-rwxrwxrwx u0_a67   u0_a67     254460 2015-03-02 17:12 ffmpeg
```

You can set the permissions to 744 , with the command below :

```
String[] command = new String[]{"/system/bin/chmod", "744",
                                "/data/data/com.example.foo/files/ffmpeg" };
```

If you are executing this command from outside activity (from a service lets say) , your permission will have to be 777 (not 744)

Answer (score 1):

In my case you need to add "sh -c" as done in the following example:

```
sh -c shellcommand
```

Hope it helps.

David

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this before exec command:

```java
try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {}

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
        }
```

Refer to: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem spontaneously while working with the ffmpeg-android project. I already had all the permissions set that others have mentioned, and I hadn't had this problem in the past.

I reverted back to an old build, which worked fine, then rebuilt the latest version and it was fine again - so the solution in my case was a simple **Clean and Rebuild**..

Try it if you're feeling desperate!