# android: Getting erro after use of FFmpeg android Library. error:Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, reverse

I have try to make video in reverse that for i have use to FFmpeg But i am not getting proper result from FFmpeg. now i am using [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) library that use to FFmpeg and gradle in compile to `compile 'com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid:0.2.5'` library. But there is one more problem when i execute any command that time i got error `Working Directory: null Environment: null` i have to declare permission in manifest file and code execute time also check file exist or not. kindly check my code and how to fix it? please share your some helpful suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**MyCode**

```
if (videoFile.exists()) {
    String vidInput = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String cmd = "-i " + vidInput + " -map_metadata:s:a 0:g " + vidoutpath;

    FFmpeg fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    });
}
```

Above code in when i pass only `-version` command that time also get same problem.

**Manifest File in uses Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**LogCat Error**

```
 Exception while trying to run: /data/data/com.videotest/files/ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/frameCount.mp4 -map_metadata:s:a 0:g /storage/emulated/0/frameCountRev.mp4
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.videotest/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/frameCount.mp4, -map_metadata:s:a, 0:g, /storage/emulated/0/frameCountRev.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
    at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working Directory: null Environment: null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950139/working-directory-null-environment-null)